# Use keyword arguments vs hash arguments in Ruby class constructor?

Tags: ruby, oop, object

I'm new to Ruby and learning how to do proper OOP with Ruby, and I have a question regarding which is the most idiomatic way for doing class constructors.

I've seen a lot of examples using hash parameters to construct an object:

```
class Person
    def initialize(params)
        @name = params[:name]
        @age = params[:age]
    end
end

person = Person.new(name:"Pepsi", age:42)
```

However, I've seen another way that I found clean and effective as well:

```
class Person
    def initialize(age:, name:)
        @name = name
        @age = age
    end
end

person = Person.new(name:"Pepsi", age:42)
```

Which way is more recommended in Ruby and why? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're both valid. Keyword arguments came about in Ruby 2.0 so some older code-bases used the first approach (`(params)`), especially when maintaining compatibility with Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.

The keyword form has benefits:

- You'll be notified of typos
- You can easily specify defaults
- Method signature communicates which options exist

The hash form has benefits:

- Won't complain about extra values
- Can be adapted to be indifferent to string vs. symbol keys
- Can use reserved keywords like `class` as keys

When writing new code, pick whichever form appeals the most.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks!